# How do you make it possible to make accounts? Python

Tags: python, authentication, load

I want to make a simple game on python, all text based. Sort of an interactive story with puzzles etc. but it is likely to be long. I want to be able to it possible for poeple to sort of, 'Save Progress'. Perhaps assign them selves a name etc? I am new to Python and am wondering if it is possible to set up a bank containing details of game play that can be accessed by entering a username and so will load the correct area of the code to allow the player to pick up where they left of.

Say they decided to quit the game just after... say, finding a clue to a murder. The computer would store the line of code they were on and get them to enter their name. Next time they could select 'Load' from the start up menu and then enter their name. The computer would then search for their name and pull up the peice of code they were at and continue as normal from there.

I am new at this so please try and explain simply. I can make a menu etc. no problems with the if's etc and make the story it's self. It is just the loading I want to add.

I hope this isn't tooooo complicated!? Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the pickle module.  It allows you to store/retrieve any python object.  One way to do this would be to have your game take place in a class, where all of the states/etc were members of that class (or derived classes).  When they wanted to save you would just pickle your class!

You are pretty new to python, I would recommend reading the documentation provided here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/ .

Python tries to be both easy to learn and comprehensive.  Most questions answer themselves!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you create your game...

Do you follow the tree of decisions that the user took in the game? If so you save the decisions in a file, that you save to a location (for example "saves/{username}/{name_of_save}.sav or just "saves/{username.sav} if every username should have only one save, but this is just a example it all depends on you). You could then allow them to select their save file and then simulate the actions from the file till you reach the point where the last decision took place.

If you would like to easily save the data to the file(s) you could also use a format like [JSON](http://www.json.org/), which python has built-in support for - read more at http://docs.python.org/library/json.html . This will allow you to easily create objects that you want to save/read from the file and use for processing.

Hope that helps...

**Just a Idea, I have not actually tried anything like this**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.sqlite.org/ or use plain text files for the beginning:) you could use the username:bitfield to encode you progress. Or use the ConfigParser module for Python and create a scetion for each user:) have fun learning:)